# Android:ListView Selector not working properly

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to apply selector to my list view ,it is a custom list view, I tried so many options but nothing worked. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am attaching my code. Thanks in Advance

**selector_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/faintblue" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/yellow" />

</selector>
```

**layout_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvChatList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlHeader"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_expandable_listview"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_expandable_listview" >

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoChats"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="No Chats"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

yellow background effect takes place effectively but blue effect is not taking place,Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set this selector as background of each row instead of listview.

Comment: ,i have another expandable list view whose children are expanded all time.all i want to do is ,add selector to its child whenever they are clicked ,same way as we do in normal list view .is it possible

Comment: Same thing will work. Just don't set this selector as background to the header layout.

Comment: you mean i should set selector for only child layout?

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView will be using Custom Layout for row item. 
So try to set background for that layout to `android:background="@drawable/selector_listview"`. 
Also make sure to have default item `<item android:drawable="@drawable/your_default_background_for_row_item" />` in your `selector_listview.xml`

Comment: yup...i did the same as it was suggested by Mr.Vipul and it worked ,thanks prashant

Comment: i have another issue with expandable list view whose children are expanded all time.all i want to do is ,add selector to its child whenever they are clicked ,same way as we do in normal list view .is it possible